# Find preceding-sibling of the parent element in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
         <p>
            <p1>c</p1>
            <a languageCode="en">a1</a>
            <a languageCode="de">a2</a>
             <ca>
                <cc>056</cc>
                <cs>BE-VAN</cs>
                <cs>BG-VLI</cs>
                <cs>BG-VLI</cs>
            </ca>
            <ca>
                <cc>056</cc>
                <cs>BE-VAN</cs>
                <cs>BG-VLI</cs>
                <cs>BG-VLI</cs>
            </ca>
        </p>
```

i tried this does not work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="p/ca/*">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1]/name() = local-name())">
            <precedingParent n="{preceding-sibling::*[1]/parent::*/name()}"></precedingParent>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but expected
output should be:

```
<precedingParent n="a"></precedingParent>
```

I am looping in ca and for instance in first occurence of cs
If a want to find the preceding sibling of the parent for parent ca for element cs ? how do i do it?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your XSLT code, just so we can sure we have the correct context. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC i have updated the question can you help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is `../preceding-sibling::*[1]/name()`. For example,

```
    <xsl:for-each select="p/ca/*">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1]/name() = local-name())">
            <precedingParent n="{../preceding-sibling::*[1]/name()}"></precedingParent>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Note that `name(../preceding-sibling::*[1])` would also work (in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0).

On the other hand, you could be slightly more efficient by having a nested loop, and getting the preceding value before selecting the child elements, to save it having to be recalculated each time:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="p/ca">
        <xsl:variable name="precedingParent" select="name(preceding-sibling::*[1])" />
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1]/name() = local-name())">
                <precedingParent n="{$precedingParent}"></precedingParent>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: can you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897747/how-to-get-following-sibling-from-xml-using-xslt-from-child-node